# How can using regex group match more than 4 digits in the string

Tags: regex, preg-match

Here is the test data:

`LW_3_1_4_5mm_70KV_LE1_4X_2.7995um_Bin1_Export00120013.tiff
LW_3_1_4_5mm_70KV_LE1_4X_2.7995um_Bin1_Export0013.tiff
LW_3_1_4_5mm_70KV_LE1_4X_2.7995um_Bin1_Export0013
0013.tiff
3.tif
0004.tif
.tif`

I just want the digits before the (.tiff),How can I got the digits?
eg. firtdata's match result is 00120013.
second data's match result is 0013.

Here is my regexPattern String :^.*(?\d{4,8}).(tiff|tif)$ ,but The result is not good ,it just get 4 digits  even there are more  than 4 digits.

[image: here is my work regex test view,but some results are not right]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is greedy and consumes as much as possible while still allowing a match.

Change the quantifier to be *reluctant* by putting a `?` after the `.*`:

```
^.*?(?\d{4,8}).(tiff|tif)$
```

Alternatively, and easier to read, you could require that the last part of the first term be a non-digit, and you should probably escape the dot, and could simplify the last part.

Try this:

```
^.*\D(\d{4,8})\.tiff?$
```

Comment: yeah,I modified your expression as :(^.*\D)?(\d{1,8})\.tiff?$ and the result is what I want.Thanks for your tip

Answer (score 0):

That is due to .* being a greedy operator. In other words it consumes every letter and only backtracks when the rest of the pattern doesn't match. By making it lazy(.*?) You will get the most amount of numbers possible(up to 8).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right expression: (^.*\D)?(\d{4,8}).(tiff|tif)$

[image: test view]