# What's wrong with the wregex?wregex not support [group] feature in native c++?

Tags: c++, regex

I want to get the the last digits (which are the sequence number) in the file name by wregex.

eg.if the file name is  **LW3_3_1_4_2mm_10X_45kV_LE1_1.0718um_0.35Tran_Export0001.tiff** I will get **0001**;

if the file name is  **LW3_3_1_4_2mm_10X_45kV_LE1_1.0718um_0.35Tran_Export0002.tiff** I will get **0002**)

But I don't Know how use the wregex  correctly in native c++.

I referred the document [regex_match Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982821.aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

bool ListFiles(wstring path, wstring mask, map<int,wstring>& files) {
    HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    wstring spec;
    stack<wstring> directories;

    directories.push(path);
    files.clear();



    while (!directories.empty()) {
        path = directories.top();
        spec = path + L"\\" + mask;
        directories.pop();

        hFind = FindFirstFile(spec.c_str(), &ffd);
        if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  {
            return false;
        }

        do {
            if (wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L".") != 0 &&
                wcscmp(ffd.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                    directories.push(path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName);
                }
                else {

                    wsmatch wideMatch;
                    wregex  fileRegex(L"(^.*\\D)?(?<fileNum>\\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$");
                    wstring target(ffd.cFileName);
                    if (regex_match(target.cbegin(), target.cend(), wideMatch, fileRegex))
                    {
                        wcout << wideMatch.str() << endl;
                    }
                    files.insert({ 0, path + L"\\" + ffd.cFileName });
                }
            }
        } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);

        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES) {
            FindClose(hFind);
            return false;
        }

        FindClose(hFind);
        hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return true;
} 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*vector<wstring> files;

    if (ListFiles(L"F:", L"*", files)) {
        for (vector<wstring>::iterator it = files.begin();
            it != files.end();
            ++it) {
            wcout << it->c_str() << endl;
        }
    }*/

    map<int, wstring> files;
    if (ListFiles(L"F:", L"*", files))
    {

    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

But there is an error,I don't know what's wrong with it. as follow pic:[image: regex error picture][image]

Edit:change  `wregex  fileRegex(L"(^.*\D)?(?<fileNum>\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$");` to  `wregex  fileRegex(L"(^.*\\D)?(?<fileNum>\\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$");`  .In fact I wrote it as second one.

Eidt2: when I changed the `L"(^.*\D)?(?<fileNum>\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$"` to `L"(^.*\\D)?\\d{1,8}.tiff$"`.it worked correctly.**Is the regex in native c++ not support group feature
?**

Comment: What error are you seeing? It crashes? It doesn't match what you're expecting? It doesn't match anything at all?

Comment: @JonCage the program crashed in VS2013,I have add a screen capture.

Comment: @xudong125 You should catch `std::regex_error` (`wregex`'s constructor is probably throwing one, by the looks of it) and inspect its `error_type`.

Comment: @Biffen the errorcode is 14,and  Error LookUp tool descript it as  ` Not enough storage is available to complete this operation` .

Comment: @xudong125 Not sure what "error lookup" you're using, but AFAIK you'll have to compare to [the list of flags](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_error/) since the value of each flag is implementation specific. Anyway, it looks like the answer below will solve the actual problem, but catching `std::regex_error` is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: Please tell us what you wanted to accomplish with the first capture group `(^.*\\D)`.

Comment: @Biffen yeah ,I find the error is 'std::regex_constants::error_syntax" but I don't know why? the regex pattern string work correctly in managed c++ and c#

Comment: @jasal Maybe the question can answer your question.How can using regex group match more than 4 digits in the string[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901874/how-can-using-regex-group-match-more-than-4-digits-in-the-string)

Comment: @xudong125 By your examples and your code it *looks like* the regex you want is `(\d{1,8})\.tiff?$`. There are numerous issues with the regex you have, so I won't list them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using a raw string for specifying your regular expression which results in an error while parsing the escape sequences `\D` and `\d`. Either write

```
wregex fileRegex(LR"(^.*\D)?(?<fileNum>\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$");
```

or escape the backslashes

```
wregex fileRegex(L"(^.*\\D)?(?<fileNum>\\d{1,8}).(tiff|tif)$");
```

The start of line character `^` should be outside of the first capture group:

```
LR"^(.*\D)?"...
```

I understand your intention behind the `\D` but it is sufficient to make the `.*` expression non-greedy by appending a `?`.

Named capture groups are **not supported** in TR1 and C++11 regexes. You have to remove the `?<fileNum>` from the second capture group.

The dot you want to match before the `tiff` must be escaped `\.`. An unescaped dot will match any character.

Try this expression, it should do the same as yours:

```
LR"^.*?(\d{1,8})\.tiff?$"
```

Comment: +1 now I see that I missed the [leaning toothpick look](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) ;-)

Comment: @jasal In fact I have tried to modified the regex pattern string  as you given, but there are still an error with it.

Comment: In fact I just want to get the digits near **.tiff**  as the file's sequence number.

Comment: I figured that. What's wrong with my solution? It will give you the digits in front of `.tiff` in the first capture group.